# How do I get div class styles to work?

Tags: html, css

For some odd reason my div class styles aren't working.

1.Yes the css is linked correctly
2. Yess all div and css properties have correct closing tags

I have this div class called `entry-title-first` then I have `entry-title-second` and `entry-title-third` but for some reason all the classes take the style of `entry-title-first` what is causing this problem?

```
.entry-title-first {
color:#fff;
font-family:Trade Gothic;
font-size:28px;
line-height:26px;
margin-top:-15px;
font-weight:900;
padding-bottom:8px;
}

.entry-title-first a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

.entry-title-second {
color:#000;
font-family:Trade Gothic;
font-size:28px;
line-height:26px;
margin-top:-15px;
font-weight:900;
padding-bottom:8px;
}

.entry-title-second a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="entry-title-first"><a href="/">Link Name</a></div>
<div class="entry-title-second"><a href="/">Link Name</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
.entry-title-first a:link, .entry-title-first  a:visited {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.entry-title-first a:hover {
  color:#f00;
}
```

Sample

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.entry-title-first {
  color:#000;
  font-family:Trade Gothic;
  font-size:28px;
  line-height:26px;
  margin-top:15px;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:8px;
}

.entry-title-first a:link, .entry-title-first  a:visited {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.entry-title-first a:hover {
  color:#f00;
}

.entry-title-second {
  color:#000;
  font-family:Trade Gothic;
  font-size:28px;
  line-height:26px;
  margin-top:15px;
  font-weight:900;
  padding-bottom:8px;
}

.entry-title-second a:link, .entry-title-second a:visited {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.entry-title-second a:hover {
  color:#ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-title-first"><a href="/">Link Name 1</a></div>
<div class="entry-title-second"><a href="/">Link Name 2</a></div>
```